# razzle Can't resolve 'fs' / 'net' (server side rendering react app)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, node-modules, server-side-rendering

Currently using https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle to implement SSR of a React Application. Running into the following errors within my node modules:

[image: ERROR: Can't resolve 'fs']

AND THIS

[image: ERROR: Can't resolve 'net']

I've added a razzle.config.js to customize the razzle config to look like this(below) and the code is still not running.

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    console: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Any idea as to why I'm receiving the errors and what I can do to fix?

Comment: Could you try writing `module.exports = { modify: config => { config.node = { fs: "empty" }; return config; } };` in your `razzle.config.js` file instead?

Comment: Great, that worked for me! thank you

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to extend the Webpack config, you need to use the [`modify` function of the `razzle.config.js` export](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle#extending-webpack).

**Example**

```
module.exports = {
  modify: config => {
    config.node = { fs: "empty" };
    return config;
  }
};
```

Comment: @FayeHayes Great! Happy to help.